# Where should I look for secrets?

Tags: tower-of-guns

Tower of Guns is a quick-playing first-person-shooter with roguelike elements: the map is semi-randomized (around the theme of each level), enemies are random, and death is permanent. There are also secrets scattered randomly around: some walls are illusory, some places are hard to get to, and some corners are simply out of the way. There are around 4 to 6 secrets per level, and I've never found more than 33% in any given level. (Also, there's a gun that unlocks if you find 5 secrets in a level.)

I want to know *where I should be looking*. I realize the game is too large to exhaustively list where each one can be found, but is there a theme or pattern of where secrets tend to appear? Are there visual cues I should look for? Do secrets always repeat, so that if I've found a secret in a particular room, that secret will always be there if I find that room in a future game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a large list of places, but I'll do my best to summarize my findings after having played this game for about a month. All of the pictures that follow should be considered spoilers.

- Right in the beginning of Foyer, turn around and run into the wall. This secret is here 100% of the time. Notice where my camera is: [image: Example 1]
- Perks can help you get to some secrets: [image: Example 1], [image: Example 2]
- The finish room for Sanctum (I believe) has a bunch of arrows going up. This is a cue that you should jump up. I believe it takes nearly 10 jumps at the standard jump height to get that secret, but there is one there. There is also a secret in the finish room for Foundry: [image: Example 1]
- The warehouse is dark, but there are some secrets to be found by jumping in the corners and off in the distance.
- Look around. Many secrets are found in very small nooks and crannies near the edges of the rooms, and you can often see a small entrance after close examination. For example, to the right of my cursor is two secrets. One you can walk into, and one you have to jump to:
  [image: Example 1]
- Don't feel stupid trying to run into walls. If you see a path that looks like it goes into a wall (Gearworks has a lot of rooms that have this feel), run into them. You never know; you might go through them.
- Turn around once in a while. You can miss a lot of secrets by not looking behind you: [image: Example 1]
- Look up. There are so many secrets that are up. The Bluegrass perk helps you with this, since you start with 3 extra jumps. Additionally, The Motivator and the Pocket Thruster are the best items to help you search up. [image: Example 1], [image: Example 2], [image: Example 3]
- Look under platforms and walkways. Sometimes if you are looking at a platform/walkway head-on you can't see these secrets, but they are often hidden right underneath other platforms/walkways.

As for your other questions..

Visual cues: look for holes in the wall, or paths that go straight into a wall. Also, platforms that you can't reach are often secrets. Most of the time, secrets are just out of reach or are hidden from plain view.

Repetition: secrets are not always repeated throughout plays, but this is because the rooms vary even across plays. You might recognize several parts of a room being the same from play to play, but the overall room will change. Oftentimes these parts do contain the same secrets from play to play, but not always.

Comment: Please do add pictures, I'm interested to see what I have missed from before!

Comment: For sure, I will play a few runs tonight and update each description with an example (assuming the RNG will let me do so).

Comment: @SadlyNot I have added pictures for what I could get in one run. If I manage to play again and make it to Sanctum (and get Warehouse to spawn -- I got foundry twice in a row unfortunately) I'll add those pictures in as well.